# The earliest point I can get a Meteor.user()

Tags: meteor

I want to update my user status to be online, meaning, run this code (coffee script...)

```
Meteor.users.update _id: Meteor.user()._id, $set: 'profile.idle': true, 'profile.online': true if Meteor.user()?
```

I don't know where to put it, (is it ok to put it in client? ) where will this code run for sure with the logged in user even if user already logged in before ?

from little googling I found that meteor start events is not the place, what is the place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

client side in a Deps.autorun block would do it

in js it would be something like

```
Deps.autorun(function(){
   if(Meteor.user()){
       Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(),{$set:{<your fields here>}});
   }
});
```

--

if you are trying to detect that users are online and can use meteorite, you might want to check out https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/profile-online

you could also roll your own, by setting up a `Meteor.setInterval` call every 10 seconds or so to update a `lastSeen` time for the user, then detect if the user is online if `lastSeen > timeNow - userTimeout[60 seconds?]`

Comment: It's not working... I get an uncought exception on computation.calc

Comment: will try the set timeout stuff, though it's not the perfect solution